# PHP/XML: Reading the position of a child node in the middle of the text of its parent

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I'm currently parsing an XML document of an instructional manual using PHP's `simplexml_load_file()` method, so I could create a digital version of the manual in PHP.

At some points of the XML, there are nodes with text, and these texts have nodes inside them.

Example:

```
<BodyText dojo-id="XXXXXX">
    This is some text in the manual with
    <HyperContainer dojo-id="XXXXXX">
        <Hyper dojo-id="XXXXXX" MarkerType="Hypertext">
            www.somelink.com
        </Hyper>
        some link
    </HyperContainer>
    in between it.
</BodyText>
```

Now if I do `echo (string)$bodyText;` (assumming that `$bodyText` contains the instance of the `<BodyText>` node in the example shown) it gives me the text:

```
"This is some text in the manual with  in between it."
```

And I can easily access the `<HyperContainer>` node on PHP by `$bodyText->HyperContainer`, and I have no problem with that.

I just need to know how can I get the position of the child node `<HyperContainer>` inside the text of its parent node `<BodyText>`, so I can insert the hyper link at that position on my markup/view code.

Comment: Have you looked at XSLT? It allows you to transform an XML into another XML, HTML or Text output. It is much easier then writing the whole transformation in PHP. Basically it is a template language just for exactly that purpose.

Comment: @ThW I have looked into using XSLT before, but the app I'm developing is getting XML files of user-specified manuals from an API. And the web app is parsing these manuals to display it to the user (With chapter controls and navigation). It's like a "one code fits all xml-files" kind of app, so XSLT isn't really an option.

Comment: Why would you think so?  Of course you might want to to some extraction/indexing on the PHP side. But for the actual transformation - XSLT is exactly designed to do that. You know that here is a XSLTProcessor class in PHP?